# Vectorization of array creation with variable indices in python - How to remove the for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

I am trying to vectorize creation of an array with variable indices that change with the loop variable. In the code snippet below, I want to remove the for loop and vectorize the array creation. Can someone kindly help?

**#Vectorize 1**

```
def abc(x):
   return str(x)+'_variable'

ar = []
for i in range(0,100):
   ar += [str('vectorize_')+abc(i)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to get much improvement from "vectorization" here since you're working with strings, unfortunately. A pure Python comprehension is about as good as you'll be able to get, because of this constraint. "Vectorized" operations are only able to take advantage of optimized numerical C code when the data are numeric.

Here's an example of one way you might do what you want here:

```py
In [4]: %timeit np.char.add(np.repeat("vectorize_variable_", 100), np.arange(100).astype(str))
108 µs ± 1.79 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

versus a pure Python comprehension:

```py
In [5]: %timeit [f"vectorize_variable_{i}" for i in range(100)]
11.1 µs ± 175 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

As far as I know, using numpy really doesn't net you any performance benefits when working with strings. Of course, I may be mistaken, and would love if I am.

If you're still not convinced, here's the same test with `n=10000`:

```py
In [6]: %timeit [f"vectorize_variable_{i}" for i in range(n)]
1.21 ms ± 23.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [7]: %timeit np.char.add(np.repeat("vectorize_variable_", n), np.arange(n).astype(str)
   ...: )
9.97 ms ± 40.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Pure Python is about 10x faster than the "vectorized" version.